# incompatible types: void cannot be converted to List<Integer>

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

i am kinda new to java programming please help, i think what i need to do is to convert the "g" array to list, it ran fine after i did this, thanks.

```
static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    int p=0;
    int q=0;
   for(int i=0; i<=a.size(); i++){
       if(a.get(i)>b.get(i)){
           p++;
       }else if(a.get(i)<b.get(i)){
           q++;
       }else break;
   }
  int g[] ={p,q};

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(g.length);

        list.add(p);
    list.add(q);


    return list;

}
```

Comment: What do you think the line `return System.out.print(g);` does?

Comment: Also just a comment on your code: pick more meaningful variable names. You have 6 one letter variables and it'll be very easy to confuse those

Comment: yeah thanks , will use more detailed variable names next time

Answer (score 0):

You can't return the result of `System.out.print` (that doesn't return anything, it is `void`). Also, you appear to want to return an `int[]` (not a `List<Integer>`). Something like,

```
static int[] compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {
    int p = 0, q = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size() && i < b.size(); i++) {
        if (a.get(i) > b.get(i)) {
            p++;
        } else if (a.get(i) < b.get(i)) {
            q++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    int g[] = { p, q };
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(g));
    return g;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but this returned array "g" in string format, it didn't work.

Comment: i needed to convert to list<integer>, it worked fine after that thanks alot.